# Null Pointer Exception if Server response not 200 ok

Tags: android

I am using webservice of java.But when i am deploying project on server at that time response returns nothing .But in my android application got null pointer exception how to handle this situation please let me know.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    JSONArray jArr;
    ArrayList<String> firstNameList=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> lastNameList=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> images=new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> primayEmailList= new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        if(result != null){
        jArr = new JSONArray(result);
        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        if(jArr.length()>0){
            for (int count = 0; count < jArr.length(); count++) {
                JSONObject obj = jArr.getJSONObject(count);
                firstNameList.add(obj.optString("firstName"));
                lastNameList.add(obj.optString("lastName"));
                if(obj.optString("imageurl").contains("profilesmall.png"))
                    images.add(null);
                else
                    images.add(obj.optString("imageurl"));
                    primayEmailList.add(obj.optString("emailid"));
                }
            }
        }
        if(firstNameList.size() == 0 && lastNameList.size() == 0) {
            firstNameList.add("No");
            lastNameList.add("Results");
            primayEmailList.add("test@mail.com");
            images.add("");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < firstNameList.size(); i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(images.get(i),firstNameList.get(i),lastNameList.get(i),primayEmailList.get(i));
            rowItems.add(item);
        }
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(BdaylistActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(BdaylistActivity.this);
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: response returns nothing but android app is getting null pointer exception?

Comment: Please give more details about your problem. Your question in it's current state doesn't say much.

Comment: I am deploying project same time i access that service.Its showing continuosly loading and after some thim showing error null pointer exception.So how i solve this issue?

Comment: `else` block has not a parenthesis, check that. I recognized that while editting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the result string return data or not

```
if(result!= null && !result.isEmpty())
```

then you can do this json parsing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question exactly and if you would want to check status code then you check by:

```
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); 
// check whether its 200 or 400 or other
```